# Laravel Caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have this function which retrieves the page's title of all urls of a website :

```
function getTitle($url)
        {
            $pages = file_get_contents($url);
            $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $pages, $match) ? $match[1] : null;
            return $title;
        }
```

Then I do a loop and it works perfectly ([Good Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM9dt.png)), but I want to use a caching for 'file_get_contents', so I did :

```
function getTitle($url)
        {
            $pages = cache()->Cache::remember('key', now()->addDay(), fn() => file_get_contents($url));
            $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $pages, $match) ? $match[1] : null;
            return $title;
        }
```

On the one side the caching works (hyper fast now) but on the other side, all the titles are the same ([Bad Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byI71.png)).

Where is my logic faulting ? This is the first time I'm using caching.

Comment: The file depends on the $url, and you are caching the `file_get_contents` independently from it, so no matter the $url value, the same cache is used.

Comment: So, what do I have to do ? How to 'connect' the $url to file_get_contents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file depends on the $url, and you are caching the `file_get_contents` independently from it, so no matter the $url value, the same cache is used.

make the cache dependent on the url. but I dont know if it's the performance upgrade you're looking for.

```
$pages = cache()->Cache::remember('key-'.$url, now()->addDay(), fn() => file_get_contents($url))
```

You should either make the cache last longer and refresh on creation or modification or have cron that refresh the cache daily.